# How to prevent multiple notifications pop-up in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to display a pop-up every 5 seconds. When a certain trigger is triggered as true (isPopup).

I tried `setInterval` function to control the execution but the notifications are popping-up every half of a second, instead of 5 seconds.

```
if (isPopup) {
      if (notificationTrigger) {
        notification.displayNotification(title, status, message);
      }
      PopUpInterval = setInterval(() => {
        notificationTrigger = !notificationTrigger;
      }, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `does not seem to work`, please be more detailed

Comment: When does the code you provided get executed?  Does this have something to do with react?